# Getting Illegalstate exception in executing xhtml

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml

I am getting some exception in doing a jsf application. This is my xhtml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

        <f:view> 
            <h:head><title>Index</title></h:head>
                <body>
                <h:form>
                    <h:outputText value="#{login.userName}"></h:outputText><br/>
                    <h:inputText id="userId" value="#{emp.userId}"></h:inputText>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{emp.check}" value="check"/>
                </h:form>
            </body>
        </f:view>   
 </html>
```

Here login is a managed bean. I am getting the username from the bean and trying to display it. And emp is another bean to which I am giving userid here.
when i run this on server i m getting following exception.

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@11a700a not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIOutput.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?
    at com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag.setProperties(OutputTextTag.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:686)
```

Comment: Have you checked `userName` value, because according to your stack trace its returning `null`. Can you post `login` bean code !

Comment: I am getting userName value from session. It is displaying when i run the above xhtml. But after i enter the id in text field and submit now i m getting org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@1b70f9e not expected type.  Expected: javax.faces.component.UIOutput.  Perhaps you're missing a tag?

Comment: Your Facelets (XHTML) file is somehow interpreted as JSP file. This indicates a seriously messed up JSF configuration. Show your `web.xml` and list the JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`, so that we can point out the cause. The currently accepted answer of khan is impossibly the "right" answer, please don't randomly accept answers for the sake of accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
           xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
           xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
           xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <f:view> 
        <h:head><title>Index</title></h:head>
            <body>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputText value="#{login.userName}"></h:outputText><br/>
                <h:inputText id="userId" value="#{emp.userId}"></h:inputText>
                <h:commandButton action="#{emp.check}" value="check"/>
            </h:form>
        </body>
    </f:view>   
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Please explain the answer in words as well.

Answer (score -1):

Update your code and put `<html>` inside `<f:view>` as in:

```
<f:view>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

           //facelet code..

         </html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: You're declaring `<f:xxx>` after it's been used for the first time. This way the `<f:view>` becomes an unknown tag.